# RDMA without the Connection Manager: skipping rdma_create_event_channel()

Tags: rdma

Is there a way to implement RDMA RC functionality without invoking the Connection Manager, and therefore skipping the rdma_create_event_channel() ?

Perhaps with a simple exchange of the necessary information through an external protocol, say UDP packets ? And then initialize the QPs with the received parameters.

Has anybody implemented any such off protocol functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IB perftest package supports both the traditional Connection Manager method and the bypass version through TCP sockets. See https://github.com/linux-rdma/perftest/blob/8332816c1c2b1911f18ba7230b7784cdb90961e3/src/perftest_communication.h#L165 and its callers.